# Lover of Fantasy

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe a person who is a lover of fantasy?
Similarly, is there a single word to describe a person who is a lover of sci-fi?

Comment: One of the beauties of language is how we can combine the same words in different ways to make new things. Whence this mania for single words? A fantasy-fiction lover loves fantasy, a science-fiction lover loves science-fiction.  A fantasist is a crafter of fantasy.

Comment: @tchrist I didn't like the way "fantasy lover" sounds :P

Comment: Which is precisely why I said *fantasy-fiction lover*.

Comment: No, I didn't like that either :)

Comment: So what if there is a single word for that, and you don't like it, either? Perhaps if you tell us the word you *will* like, we can speed up the process considerably.

Comment: Fantasy lover (or fantasy-fiction lover) just sounded rather unwieldy. I'm looking for one word that is elegant - and if I don't like that either, then I'll just accept the best one. I'm just seeing if there's one word for it, and if I happen to like it too, well, that's bonus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find *fantasy lover* too suggestive and *fantasy-fiction lover* too unwieldy, then perhaps the problem is with the *lover* part, not the *fantasy* part.

My favorite is ***fantasy buff***, which doesn’t seem too unwieldy.

A *fantasy fan* is easy too, and then there’s always *fantasy devotee* and *fantasy aficionado*. Whether *fantasy addict* or *fantasy junkie* are also too connotative of other matters, I leave to you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single word for 'lover of fantasy'.

Answer (score 0):

While to many people it has negative connotations, "nerd" could serve your purposes admirably. As could "fan" or "enthusiast".

Comment: I'd say "geek" is more fitting, at least according to this [diagram](http://www.buzzfeed.com/scott/nerd-venn-diagram). *Fantasy/sci-fi* => "Intelligence" and *lover* => "Obsession" :-)

Comment: In the contexts I've heard it in, a nerd is anyone who is very interested in something. You can have DnD nerds and you can have Baseball nerds.

I would have switched 'nerd' and 'geek' in that diagram.

Comment: I agree the names for the intersections seem arbitrary. I don't think the diagram was meant to be precise, but rather humorous. It's why I added the :-) at the end of my comment.